# Salesforce lightning combobox hide label with css

Tags: css, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am editing record detail page inside salesforce community web site. When editing a record I don't want customer to change its status which is a combobox. I have hidden the combobox by adding css

```
.slds-combobox__input {

dispaly:none;

}
```

but it is still showing the label of the combobox and required field indicator. I tried to hide it with

```
.slds-form-element__label {
display:none;
}
```

but it hides all the labels on the form. How can I hide the child label of the combobox only.

Answer (score 1):

please see the below documentation which says you can declare a variant property on lightning-combobox like this

<lightning-combobox **variant="label-hidden"** name="Status" data-record-id={campaignMember.Id} value={campaignMember.Status} options={campaignMemberStatusItem} onchange={handleStatusChange}>

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification